# Copying file from Azure File Share- The content of the file is getting appended with /r/n

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-file-share

we are writing the following command to copy the file from the Azure function app local to our file share i.e.; mounted in the VM:\

Command:

```
    Set-AzStorageFileContent -Source 'C:/home/site/wwwroot/HttpTrigger2/demo.tfvars' -ShareName "storage-fileshare" -Path "Demo/Test" -Context $destctx -Force -ContentEncoding "UTF-8"  #-Properties @{"ContentEncoding" = "UTF-8"}
```

The issue that we facing now is the Encoding of the file content is changing when it is being written in the file share.

The result that we are getting:
**"tfv_storage_account_name="sandeep"\r\ntfv_location_storage="Brazil"\r\ntfv_account_tier="Standard"\r\n**

/n/r gets appended in our original file it was not there

We expect to file at file share like the below content

```
tfv_storage_account_name="sandeep" 
tfv_location_storage="Brazil"
tfv_account_tier="Standard"
```

In the command line, I tried to append the followings:
1.    -Properties @{"ContentEncoding" = "UTF-8"}
2.    -ContentEncoding "UTF-8"
3.    -Encoding UTF-8, etc.

Anyone faced this issue of why file content gets appended with /n/r etc?

Comment: What are you trying to do can you explain it clearly , can you provide us your source file ?

Comment: Hello @RithwikBojja,

Comment: The source file contains the following lines:

tfv_storage_account_name="sandeep" 
tfv_location_storage="Brazil"
tfv_account_tier="Standard"

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and I got expected results as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontext?view=azps-9.5.0):

Firstly i have used below commands:

```
$destctx=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "name of storage acc" -StorageAccountKey "Storage acc key"
New-AzStorageDirectory -ShareName "File share name" -Path "Demo" -Context $destctx
Set-AzStorageFileContent -Source "C:\Users\Downloads\vars.tfvar" -ShareName "File Share name" -Path "Demo/Fest" -Context $destctx -Force
```

Output:

Checked using `cat Filename`command :

[image]

Then checked the same in portal:

[image]

Comment: Hello Rithwik, I tried the same but the result is not coming as desired.

Just wanted to add on, I have the file in local of function app server and from there I am copying it to file share. The file share is mounted in an AzureVM.

Comment: Yeah I have done the same and got required output.